# Working with a timer to show the label for some time

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I am working on [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application. I have a windows form in which a label is set visible to false by default. I want to set property *visible* to `true` for 10 seconds and then  after to false. I have dragged the timer control and set the interval to 1000 miliseconds, that is, 1 second, and I have written the code in form load event:

```
    timer1.Start();
    if (timer1.Interval == 5000)
    {            
        timer1.Stop();
    }
```

But it is not setting the label visible to `false`. Why?

In which event do I have to fire this code so that when the timer starts and when will it be 5 seconds and then the label will be set to false? Is that possible in C#?

Comment: What about you sit down for a minute and try to make a question that is logically sensible? And no, it is not the langauge. See, your question and description is nice - but has TOTALLY NOTHING (!) to do with the code sample you give. You do not say what you have tried, indead dumping isa beginner question, and a non-sensical, non-documented, not related code example. BAD. Sit down, do your homework, then ask for specific help including a sensible question and code sample and what you have tried.

Comment: There's no code which says Label1.Visible = false that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below code.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 10000;
        timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        label1.Visible = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop(); //If timer is not stopped, timer1_Tick event will be called for every 10 seconds
        label1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is only one event for this timer -> `tick` which must be handled

```
timer1.Interval = 5000;
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
label1.Visible = true;
timer1.Start();


  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     label1.Visible = false;
  }
```

Comment: thank you sir for helping sorry for the silly question because i thing totally dumb. i am a newbie to programming thanks for solving my doubt
:)

Comment: You could also use `dispatchtimer` and `elapsedtimer` ;) +1 Vlad L

Comment: @shariq_khan I would highly recommend you to read a book like C# for dummies or something like that (no offence, they are really good and helpfull). You will get a full image of how the things are working

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), by double clicking on the timer you should get this function in the code behind:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Try changing the label visibility in this function, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Used this statement:

```
 Label1.Visible = false
```

I think there is a problem with the attribute of Label1.